# lock or not with message queue

Tags: c, linux, message-queue

I'm trying to use message queue in Linux, is it possible to do the below

process 1 has message queue named one

producer 1 & 2 send message to one with no lock mechanism, is that ok ?

Comment: Generally speaking it depends on what you mean by "lock", and what you mean by "queue". Strictly speaking there are CPU atomic instructions that can be used instead of spin locks or thread synchronization primitives provided by OS.

Comment: I mean System V or POSIX message queues

Comment: And by lock, let's say emaphore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sys V message queues provide priority, so that a particular queue recipient can be specified and can get messages "aimed" at it.  With no contention.  Queue readers can access any message as well depending on the mtype value in `msgrcv()`.  POSIX message queues are a little different.   Generally you can employ Sys V queues without having to worry about locking resources. Sys V semaphores queues and shared memory do have some downsides as well.  Like the fact that they are kernel persistent.

Try `http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/`

Comment: Thanks Jim, I think I don't need a lock with POSIX queue as well, please check this link and let me know if I'm wrong.      http://mij.oltrelinux.com/devel/unixprg/#ipc__sockets

Comment: Your link, as I read it, is not POSIX msg queues, but sockets. And you can code around the need for resource control on POSIX queues as well. It just that it is simpler to implement on Sys V, IMO.

Comment: POSIX message queues are also kernel persistent. See man mq_overview under (Persistence): POSIX message queues have kernel persistence: if not removed by mq_unlink(3), a message queue will exist until  the  system  is shut down.